# Product of altitudes in a triangle.

Tags: geometry

> The base $AB$ of a Triangle is $1$ and $h$ of $C$ from $AB$ is $\leq 0.5$. Then find maximum value of product of altitudes of triangle .

Try: let  in triangle $ABC$ , where $h\leq 1/2$

using area of triangle $\displaystyle \triangle=\frac{1}{2}\times 1\times h\leq \frac{1}{4}$.

Could some help me how to find product of altudes. Thanks

Comment: By altitudes do you mean the length of the perpendicular lines through each opposite vertices?

Comment: Yes i mean same thing John Glenn

Comment: I think $h$ is not allowed to go below $\frac12$ since the "altitudes" would no longer lie on the sides of the triangle. Is that allowed?

Comment: Consider this [diagram](https://ggbm.at/njQUkKvh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the altitude $h_C$ is given the problem is reduced to finding the maximum value of $h_A\cdot h_B$. As the length $AB$ is also given the area of the triangle $S=\frac{1}{2} AB\cdot h_C$ is constant. Observing that 
$S=\frac{1}{2} BC\cdot h_A=\frac{1}{2} AC\cdot h_B$ one obtains:
$$
h_A\cdot h_B=\frac{4S^2}{AC\cdot BC}=2S\sin\hat{C}.
$$
Thus the maximum value of $h_A\cdot h_B$ for given $S$ corresponds to the maximum value of $\sin\hat{C}$, which is, provided that $h_C\le \frac{1}{2}AB$, equal to $1$.

Finally one obtains:
$$
\max(h_Ah_Bh_C)=\max(2S\cdot h_C)=\max(h_C^2)\cdot AB=0.25.
$$